# Android Studio 2.1 Login Activity Needs Explanation

Tags: java, android-studio

I've recently started android programming with android studio. In version 2.1 you can add a login activity. I have seen other login activity codes on internet but I really have difficulty understanding the android studio generated logiin activity code. I couldnt even find explanations for some of the class names in the code in android developers. Can anyone help me out with this.

https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/231191/Login-Activity-class-generated-from-Andr

Comment: What could you not understand in that?

Comment: If you don't understand what it does yet, read & learn from the tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/index.html which should explain most pieces. Or take one of the free online courses mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info - explaining entire source files isn't effective nor on topic.